# Cómo ocultar una pantalla completa con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, display, hide

Soy principiante en JavaScript and CSS. Estoy practicando haciendo algunos projectos.
Ahora estoy haciendo una calculadora de calificaciones escolares, donde si tu promedio es superior a 7 aparece una pantalla por encima de la pantalla principal para felicitarte. Declaré la propiedad "display" en CSS como "none" para intentar cambiarla a "flex" en javascript con *style.display = "flex"*.

El código de los estilos en CSS para la pantalla emergente es el siguiente...

```
.backgroundUp {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-40%);
    background-color: rgba(36, 38, 46, 0.808);
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Luego intento ocultar el .backgroundUp que contiene todos los elementos de la pantalla emergente con el siguiente código en JS...

```
function calculateGrade() {

    var inputValues = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
    var conca = "";
    if (inputValues.length == 5 ){
        for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
            var inputvalue = inputValues[i].value;
            conca = conca + "+" + inputvalue;
            var resultado= eval(conca);
            var output = resultado / 5;
        }
        document.getElementById('prom').innerText=output;
        document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundUp').style.display = "flex";
    }else{
        alert("Please, fill all the fields.");
    }
}
```

Podrían ayudarme, por favor? Qué está mal o necesito hacer?

Comment: Prueba con `document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundUp').style.display = "block";` en vez de `flex`

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Estás en la comunidad en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta para evitar que sea cerrada o trasládala a la [comunidad en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Por favor, traduce el título de tu consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante tener la consola abierta para poder ver los errores. En tu caso tendrás un *Uncaught TypeError* indicando que no es posible leer las propiedades de `undefined`, porque `document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundUp').display` no está definido (no existe).

`document.getElementsByClassName()` devuelve una colección (array) de elementos.

Si solo tienes un elemento con clase `backgroundUp`, será el índice cero de la colección:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundUp')[0].style.display = 'flex';
```

Si tienes múltiples elementos con la misma clase y quieres aplicar cambios a todos ellos, tendrás que recorrer el array:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('backgroundUp').forEach(element => {
    element.style.display = 'flex';
});
```

---

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo utilizar los métodos `document.querySelector()` y `document.querySelectorAll()`, en los que puedes utilizar los mismos selectores que en CSS.

[Document.querySelector() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

[Document.querySelectorAll() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! Al final terminé utilizando element.querySelector() y en el código HTML agregué la propiedad style al elemento.